# Specifying argument Array length

Tags: multidimensional-array, parameters, typescript

Is it possible to specify the length of a double array upon parameter settings? for example:

```
class Matrix4x4{
    constructor(matrix: /*must be a 4x4 number matrix*/){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible using Tuples.  (see : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.3.3 )

something like...

```
type TMatrixRow4x4 = [number, number, number, number];
type TMatrix4x4 = [TMatrixRow4x4, TMatrixRow4x4, TMatrixRow4x4, TMatrixRow4x4];

class Matrix4x4{
    constructor(matrix: TMatrix4x4){}
}
```

You can change it around for any size matrix you might need.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to limit the length of the array, and only need to define the array's elements you can use tuples like in David D.'s answer. However, in your case that would be the same as doing `number[][]`.

Otherwise it gets a little tricky.

```
interface Array4<T> {
    0: T;
    1: T;
    2: T;
    3: T;
    // Copied directly from the 'lib.d.ts' file
    push(...items: T[]): number;
}

interface MatrixArray4x4<T> {
    0: T;
    1: T;
    2: T;
    3: T;
    // Copied directly from the 'lib.d.ts' file
    map<U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): U[];
}

// Alias for clarity
type MatrixData4x4 = MatrixArray4x4<Array4<number>>;

class Matrix4x4{
    constructor(matrix: MatrixData4x4){
    }
}
```

Works

```
var matrix: MatrixData4x4 = [
    [1, 3, 3, 7],
    [1, 9, 8, 4],
    [9, 0, 0, 1],
    [2, 0, 3, 8],
];
```

The type of `a` is `number`.

```
var a = matrix[0][0];
```

The type of `b` is `any`. If `--noImplicitAny` is set, a type error will occur.

```
var b = matrix[4][0];
```

Works

```
new Matrix4x4([
    [1, 3, 3, 7],
    [1, 9, 8, 4],
    [9, 0, 0, 1],
    [2, 0, 3, 8],
]);
```

Error: Property `4` is not assignable in `MatrixData4x4`.

```
new Matrix4x4([
    [1, 3, 3, 7],
    [1, 9, 8, 4],
    [9, 0, 0, 1],
    [2, 0, 3, 8],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
]);
```

Error: Property `map` missing in the literal object.

```
new Matrix4x4({
    0: [1, 3, 3, 7],
    1: [1, 9, 8, 4],
    2: [9, 0, 0, 1],
    3: [2, 0, 3, 8],
});
```

Error: Property `3` missing in `MatrixData4x4`.

```
new Matrix4x4([
    [1, 3, 3, 7],
    [1, 9, 8, 4],
    [9, 0, 0, 1],
]);
```

Error: Property `3` missing in `Array4<number>`.

```
new Matrix4x4([
    [1, 3, 3],
    [1, 9, 8, 4],
    [9, 0, 0, 1],
    [9, 0, 0, 1],
]);
```

Error: Type `string` is not assignable to `number`.

```
new Matrix4x4([
    [1, '3', 3, 5],
    [1, 9, 8, 4],
    [9, '0', 0, 1],
    [9, 0, 0, '1'],
]);
```

The limitation is that `MatrixArray4x4` and `Array4` don't extend `Array`. So type errors will occur if `Array` methods are called on it and they're not defined.

Works, since `map` is defined above in `MatrixArray4x4`.

```
matrix.map((x) => x[3]);
```

Works, since `push` is defined above in `Array4`.

```
matrix.map((arr) => arr.push(4));
```

Error: Property `push` doesn't exist on the type `MatrixArray4x4`.

```
matrix.push([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Error: Property `map` doesn't exist on the type `Array4`.

```
matrix.map((arr) => {
    arr.map((x) => x[3]);
});
```

They way I got around this was to make an interface called `ArrayMethods` containing all the methods from the `Array` class without the element definition. I then extended that interface to make new limited length array interfaces.